# Writing regular expression for String

Tags: regex, expression

What will be the regular expression if I want to match var/value string seperated by = e.g. `NUM="0000000000"` where string always start with 'NUM' string, then has '=' sign, then open quote symbol, the ten 0's and finally closed with closing quote symbol.

Comment: How about `/^NUM="0000000000"$/`

Comment: `/NUM="0{10}"/` or `/NUM="[0]+"/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering why you'd need something like that...

Anyway, if you want a regex you can use something like:

```
^NUM="0{10}"$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gJ7pD1/1)**

[image]

Comment: ^(.*)NUM="0{10}"(.*) if you wan to have any characters in both end of this pattern.